# Override an array in azure app service application settings

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

In my .NET Core application, I added an array to the appsettings.json, which looks like this:

```
{
  "SettingsA": {
    "PropA": [
        "ChildObjectA": {
          ...
        },
        "ChildObjectB": {
          ...
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I would like to override that value from Application Settings in my azure app service, so that it will have empty array:

```
{
  "SettingsA": {
    "PropA": []
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to put

```
SettingsA:PropsA  ->  []
```

In the application settings, but it doesn't seem to override the value of appsettings.json

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer here https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2016/03/23/iconfiguration-in-netcore/ is that you can override elements within an array or add additional elements but he says that you can't override the entire array, which seems strange.

Syntax for overriding uses zero-based access such as SettingsA:PropA:0:Something and I have tried this on App Services and can confirm it works.

Comment: This is the only relevant answer and it is correct. The short answer is the following syntax in Application settings: ArrayName:Index Value. From the question: SettingsA:PropA:0:ChildObjectA value

Comment: On a linux app service, use `__` instead of `:`

Answer (score 14):

Just to top up all the great answers already given here, here is how we did it in our real life scenario.

We needed a collection of supported languages to be configured in our app settings. Here is how it looked in the appSettings.json in our .NET Core project:

```
{
    ...

    "SupportedLanguages": [
        {
            "Code": "en-AU",
            "Name": "English (Australia)"
        },
        {
            "Code": "en-GB",
            "Name": "English (United Kingdom)"
        },
        {
            "Code": "en-US",
            "Name": "English (United States)"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is how it ended up looking in our Azure App Service:

[image]

It's a bit fiddly, especially if you have a larger or more complex hierarchy, but I don't think there's another way for now.

Answer (score 3):

To to this using a multiplataform syntax on Azure use __

This way works for both Windows and Linux deployed App Services:

```
SettingsA__PropA__0__Something
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `AddEnvironmentVariables` property to achieve [override appsettings on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256615/net-core-webjob-configuration-in-azure-app-service/49271202#49271202) to local settings.

First configure the setting in portal:
[image]

**Note**: The value here is null.

To override nested keys in the App Settings section we can define a variable using the full path `SettingsA:PropA` as name or using double underscore `SettingsA__PropA`. You could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/).

In local, you could configure as below:
In Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        public IConfiguration configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<SettingsOptions>(configuration.GetSection("SettingsA"));

        }
```

In appsettings.json:

```
{"SettingsA": {
    "PropA": ["a","b"]
    }
}
```

In HomeController:

```
private readonly IOptions<SettingsOptions> options;
        public HomeController(IOptions<SettingsOptions> options)
        {
            this.options = options;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var value = options.Value;
            ViewBag.Index = value.PropA+"success";
            return View();
        }
```

In SettingsOption:

```
public class SettingsOptions
    {
        public string SettingsA { get; set; }
        public string PropA { get; set; }
    }
```

After you publish the project to azure, it will override the PropA value.
For more details about how to read appsetting from asp.net core, please follow this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453495/how-to-read-appsettings-values-from-config-json-in-asp-net-core).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question was specifically about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange behaviour by microsoft team. Looks like they are not aware of how the reality looks like.

I ended up with having a string with comma separated values instead of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the settings in the [**Application settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#app-settings) are injected into your `appsettings.json` **at runtime**, overriding existing settings.
 It will not change the appsettings.json file, because Azure GUI (Connection trings, Application settings) uses environment variables internally.

Here is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298562/azure-application-settings-not-overriding-my-appsettings-json-file-values) for you to refer. You could override the settings during release via VSTS. Here are the links to [Colin's ALM Corner Build & Release Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks) and [tutorial](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/managing-config-for-net-core-web-app-deployments-with-tokenizer-and-replacetokens-tasks). For more details, you could refer to psycho's reply in the above post.

> If there is a need for an appsettings.json's value to be overwritten during VSTS release activity (before it will be published to Azure), Colin's ALM Corner Build & Release Tools can be used.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's what I meant. I meant `override` not replace

Comment: This is not true for webjobs